# NullReferenceException with Nullable DateTime despite null check

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack

`GetTodayItemCount()` attempts to get today's item count using `CreatedDtt` in the `Items` model. Because `CreatedDtt` is a Nullable Datetime (`DateTime?`), I use a ternary operator within the `Where`'s lambda expression to make sure I am not trying to access the date of a null value later on in my equality comparison.

However, I still get the classic `NullReferenceException? Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error, and I can confirm that `row.CreatedDtt.Value.Date` is where the issue is at.

```
  public Int64 GetTodayItemCount()
        {
            OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(dbConn, SqlServerDialect.Provider);

            using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.Open())
            {
                SqlExpression<Items> itemMatch = db.From<Items>()
                     .Where(row =>
                        (row.CreatedDtt.HasValue ?
                        row.CreatedDtt.Value.Date : DateTime.MinValue) == DateTime.Today
                      );

                Int64 itemCount = db.Count(itemMatch);
                db.Close();

                return itemCount;
            }
        }
```

How is `row.CreatedDtt.Value.Date` being accessed when I am checking for its valid value beforehand, and how can I accomplish the desired outcome of `GetTodayItemCount()` without getting a `NullReferenceException` error?

Since the solution doesn't seem to be as straightforward as I had predicted, I am adding the stack trace below in case there is any use in it:

```
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.GetQuotedColumnName(ModelDefinition tableDef, String memberName)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.GetMemberExpression(MemberExpression m)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Visit(Expression exp)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Visit(Expression exp)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Visit(Expression exp)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Visit(Expression exp)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.AppendToWhere(String condition, Expression predicate)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlExpression`1.Where(Expression`1 predicate)
   at GroupRedemptionsScanner.DBHandlers.GetTodayItemCount() in [directory/file/line number etc]
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I confirmed it by simply removing the `Date` property from the code. When I do that, I get no errors, but naturally the equality comparison isn't being done properly.

Comment: Is there a different way of implementing this?

Comment: I tried that as well, got the same error. It's quite strange

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have added the stack trace as well, which points directly at the where expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply C# logic to RDBMS Server columns. If you want to test fuzzy precision data types like Dates you should use a range instead, e.g:

```
.Where(row => row.CreatedDtt != null && 
              row.CreatedDtt >= DateTime.Now.Date && 
              row.CreatedDtt <  DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assumed it had to do with something about the RDBMS translation. This worked great. Any reason you chose `DateTime.Now.Date` as opposed to `DateTime.Today`?

Comment: I just never use .Today, but it should work just the same

Comment: It's really amazing how to can get help from ServiceStack's CTO within minutes of posting your question on StackOverflow

Comment: @jgozal we aim to please :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error in every way you could imagine but I couldn't. The only way was explicitly leaving a row in null. But I don't know if it's a possible case. Anyway, I propose you to refactor it using Null Propagation. This way:

```
.Where(row => row?.CreatedDtt?.Date == DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: With this I get an error about not being able to use a null propagating operator within  an expression tree lambda. Thank you for all your help in any case :)